# Understanding/Helping an Entrenched "Conspiracy Theorist"

Tags: reference-request, clinical-psychology, psychiatry

I'm currently interested in gathering information and knowledge related to advanced "conspiracy theorists" to help with challenging/talking/helping them recover.

***To define a severe/entrenched "conspiracy theorist" see the following attributes:***

1. Has the urge/need to "inform" new people they meet.
2. Rejects facts or proof (All of the reading I have read has indicated attempting to reason with someone like this will only push them deeper into their hole)
3. Has the inability to think of most other things in life other than the "end of the world" (an addiction)
4. Consumes large amounts of information related to the "end of the world" or "conspiracy theories" from other people that have similar thoughts.
5. Might start street prophesizing (imagine the guy on the street with a sign that says, "the end is nigh, repent")

***Some of the topics that one of these entrenched conspiracy theorists might spout are as follows (NOTE: This is not a fully inclusive list of theories)***

1. 9/11 conspiracy, Mayan end of the world (EOTW), other general EOTW scenarios.
2. Planet Nibiru
3. Pope is the Antichrist
4. World ending comet
5. Three Days of Darkness
6. [Rapture (Etc)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V4Ul4VEf_xY)

[There's another question that goes into the understanding of a conspiracy theorist](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/3937/what-are-the-mechanics-behind-the-mind-of-a-conspiracy-theorist), but it does not touch how one might go about helping an individual.

I'm truly trying to get advice/help/resources to help a person that might be afflicted with an entrenched belief in one or many conspiracy theories.  While I understand the best way for someone to find their way out of this belief system is to have them come to the conclusion by themselves, I'm looking for advice/help that third parties can perform to assist with the progress.

Comment: I think overgeneralization of patternicity and agenticity has some role.